# Printing value of a unique counter outside mdframed

Tags: counters, mdframed

I have defined commands for a unique counter, i can retrieve the values if the counter unique name is not defined inside mdframed, what could be the problem, i cant seem to retrive the value if counter name defined inside mdframed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{uniquecounter}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\UniqueCounterNew{answers}
\pagestyle{plain}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\DefNewAnswersName}[2]{%
  % #1 is unique counter value
  % #2 is name of anchor
  \@namedef{answers@#2}{a#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\NewAnswersName}[1]{%
  \UniqueCounterCall{answers}\DefNewAnswersName{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\PrintAnswersName}[1]{%
  \@nameuse{answers@#1}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
 \NewAnswersName{first}%
 \NewAnswersName{second}%
\begin{mdframed}
%inside md framed environment it has problems
  \NewAnswersName{third}%
\end{mdframed}
 \noindent
  first: \PrintAnswersName{first}\\%
  second: \PrintAnswersName{second}\\
  third: \PrintAnswersName{third}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\@namedef` works as long it is not inside a group, the later being true if you apply `\@namedef` in `mdframed` environment (as with any environment), in this case the `\@namedef` holds a value only inside that environment, outside it is empty, but still defined (outerwise it would stop with an error message)

One solution is to prepend a `\global` just before `\@namedef`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{uniquecounter}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\UniqueCounterNew{answers}
\pagestyle{plain}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\DefNewAnswersName}[2]{%
  % #1 is unique counter value
  % #2 is name of anchor
  \global\@namedef{answers@#2}{a#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\NewAnswersName}[1]{%
  \UniqueCounterCall{answers}\DefNewAnswersName{#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\PrintAnswersName}[1]{%
  \@nameuse{answers@#1}%
}

%%%% Explicitly 'wrong' commands, that do not what is expected, because
%%%% of the \begingroup ... \endgroup

\newcommand*{\GroupedDefNewAnswersName}[2]{%
  % #1 is unique counter value
  % #2 is name of anchor
\begingroup
 \@namedef{answers@#2}{a#1}%
\endgroup
}



\newcommand*{\GroupedNewAnswersName}[1]{%
  \UniqueCounterCall{answers}\GroupedDefNewAnswersName{#1}%
}


\makeatother


\begin{document}
 \NewAnswersName{first}%
 \NewAnswersName{second}%
\begin{mdframed}
%inside md framed environment it has problems
  \NewAnswersName{third}%
\end{mdframed}

 \GroupedNewAnswersName{fourth}%
 \GroupedNewAnswersName{fifth}%


 \noindent
  first: \PrintAnswersName{first}\\%
  second: \PrintAnswersName{second}\\
  third: \PrintAnswersName{third} \\
  fourth: \PrintAnswersName{fourth} \\
  fifth: \PrintAnswersName{fifth}
\end{document}
```

I introduced two commands, applying a grouping, which show that the grouping delivers empty `\@namedef` values. Do not use them, as they are logically wrong.

[image]

**Remark** The broken frame of `mdframed` in the snapshot is just a pdfviewer issue, not due to LaTeX.

Comment: make \global how could i miss that.. thanx.